# How to call a method AFTER a view has rendered in MAUI - OnAppearing fires too soon

Tags: maui

I have some animations that I want to trigger once the view has loaded.

Some of them rely on position values of other views on the page but at the time that OnAppearing fires, the X and Y values for these controls have not been set.

Others can just run by themselves but because they start in OnAppearing, the first few frames aren't rendered.

Adding a Task.Delay into the start of the methods solves the problem but is obviously not great.

Is there any way to create such a method or maybe a way to do it with behaviours? They need to trigger automatically, not in response to some control event like TextChanged etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it from the native side, In Ios, you can override the **ViewDidLoad** method in custom renderer like:

```
 public class MyPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            //call before ViewWillAppear and only called once
        }

        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        }
    }
```

and android, override the **OnAttachedToWindow** method:

```
public class MyPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public MyPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
        {
            base.OnAttachedToWindow();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to subclass ContentPage and PageViewController, and add a custom event that is called on ViewDidAppear. This requires that you set up handlers. I have added my code for iOS, but other platforms should be similar. You can read more about handlers at [the MAUI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize).

The nice thing about this approach is that you can access the event handler from XAML, and start your animation from the code behind:

```
<controls:TSContentPage
         ...
         IOSViewDidAppear="TSContentPage_IOSViewDidAppear">
```

TSContentPage.cs:

```
public class TSContentPage : ContentPage
    {
        public event EventHandler IOViewDidAppear;

        public void InvokeViewDidAppear()
        {
            IOSViewDidAppear.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
```

TSContentPageHandler.cs (based on MAUIs [PageHandler.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/40ed78b4631c767a682e6b28a547c4e5c675f943/src/Core/src/Handlers/Page/PageHandler.cs#L10)):

```
public partial class TSContentPageHandler : ContentViewHandler, IPageHandler
{
    public static new IPropertyMapper<IContentView, IPageHandler> Mapper =
        new PropertyMapper<IContentView, IPageHandler>(ContentViewHandler.Mapper)
        {
#if IOS || TIZEN
            [nameof(IContentView.Background)] = MapBackground,
#endif
            [nameof(ITitledElement.Title)] = MapTitle,
        };

    public static new CommandMapper<IContentView, IPageHandler> CommandMapper =
        new(ContentViewHandler.CommandMapper);

    public TSContentPageHandler() : base(Mapper, CommandMapper)
    {
    }

    public TSContentPageHandler(IPropertyMapper? mapper)
        : base(mapper ?? Mapper, CommandMapper)
    {
    }

    public TSContentPageHandler(IPropertyMapper? mapper, CommandMapper? commandMapper)
        : base(mapper ?? Mapper, commandMapper ?? CommandMapper)
    {
    }
}
```

TSContentPageHandler.MaciOS.cs (based on MAUIs [PageHandler.iOS.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/40ed78b4631c767a682e6b28a547c4e5c675f943/src/Core/src/Handlers/Page/PageHandler.iOS.cs#L15)):

```
public partial class TSContentPageHandler : ContentViewHandler, IPlatformViewHandler
{
    protected override ContentView CreatePlatformView()
    {
        _ = VirtualView ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(VirtualView)} must be set to create a LayoutView");
        _ = MauiContext ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(MauiContext)} cannot be null");

        if (ViewController == null)
            ViewController = new TSPageViewController(VirtualView, MauiContext);

        if (ViewController is TSPageViewController pc && pc.CurrentPlatformView is ContentView pv)
            return pv;

        if (ViewController.View is ContentView cv)
            return cv;

        throw new InvalidOperationException($"PageViewController.View must be a {nameof(ContentView)}");
    }

    public static void MapBackground(IPageHandler handler, IContentView page)
    {
        if (handler is IPlatformViewHandler invh && invh.ViewController is not null)
        {
            invh.ViewController.View?.UpdateBackground(page);
        }
    }

    public static void MapTitle(IPageHandler handler, IContentView page)
    {
        if (handler is IPlatformViewHandler invh && invh.ViewController is not null)
        {
            if (page is ITitledElement titled)
            {
                invh.ViewController.Title = titled.Title;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TSPageViewController.cs:

```
public class TSPageViewController : PageViewController
{
    readonly TSContentPage _contentPage;

    public TSPageViewController(IView page, IMauiContext mauiContext) : base(page, mauiContext)
    {
        if(page is TSContentPage)
        {
            _contentPage = page as TSContentPage;
        }
    }

    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
        _contentPage?.InvokeViewDidAppear();
    }
}
```

Remember to register your new handler in MauiProgram.cs:

```
builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
    {
        handlers.AddHandler(typeof(TSContentPage), typeof(TSContentPageHandler));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is using an old/legacy approach, this simple but important feature is unfortunately still not properly documented or even easily possible (actually currently not possible without custom code, [according to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1167870/net-maui-how-to-run-method-after-page-is-shown)).

**The following is the closest I could get to achieving a cross-platform, re-usable "after-loaded" callback.**

Note that the provided code is for Windows and Mac/Catalyst but the Mac version should also work for iOS. I don't know about Android but it should be possible to override `onCreate` or other callbacks in a similar way.

We start by defining a class extending `ContentPage`, which we will use later:

```cs
public class BaseContentPage : ContentPage
{
    public virtual void OnAppeared()
    {
        // Override in your own content page derived from this class
    }
}
```

then create two custom page handlers for Windows and one for Mac/iOS:

```cs
#if IOS || MACCATALYST
using Microsoft.Maui.Handlers;
using Microsoft.Maui.Platform;

namespace MyApp;

internal class PageHandlerMac : PageHandler
{
    class MacViewController : PageViewController
    {
        readonly BaseContentPage _contentPage;
        
        public MacViewController(IView page, IMauiContext mauiContext) : base(page, mauiContext)
        {
            if(page is BaseContentPage)
            {
                _contentPage = page as BaseContentPage;
            }
        }

        public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
            _contentPage.OnAppeared();
        }
    }

    protected override Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView CreatePlatformView()
    {
        _ = VirtualView ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(VirtualView)} must be set to create a LayoutView");
        _ = MauiContext ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(MauiContext)} cannot be null");

        if (ViewController == null)
            ViewController = new MacViewController(VirtualView, MauiContext);

        if (ViewController is PageViewController pc && pc.CurrentPlatformView is Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView pv)
            return pv;

        if (ViewController.View is Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView cv)
            return cv;

        throw new InvalidOperationException($"PageViewController.View must be a {nameof(Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView)}");
    }
}
#endif
```

for Windows:

```cs
#if WINDOWS
using Microsoft.Maui.Handlers;
using Microsoft.Maui.Platform;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;

namespace MyApp;

internal class PageHandlerWindows : PageHandler
{
    protected override void ConnectHandler(ContentPanel platformView)
    {
        base.ConnectHandler(platformView);

        if (platformView is FrameworkElement frameworkElement && VirtualView is BaseContentPage baseContentPage)
        {
            // Attach Windows-specific logic here
            frameworkElement.GotFocus += (sender, e) => baseContentPage.OnAppeared();
        }
    }

    protected override void DisconnectHandler(ContentPanel platformView)
    {
        if (platformView is FrameworkElement frameworkElement && VirtualView is BaseContentPage baseContentPage)
        {
            // Detach Windows-specific logic here
            frameworkElement.GotFocus -= (sender, e) => baseContentPage.OnAppeared();
        }

        base.DisconnectHandler(platformView);
    }
}
#endif
```

now include these handlers in your `CreateMauiApp` method (MauiProgram.cs):

```cs
builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
{
#if MACCATALYST
    handlers.AddHandler(typeof(BaseContentPage), typeof(PageHandlerMac));
#elif WINDOWS
    handlers.AddHandler(typeof(BaseContentPage), typeof(PageHandlerWindows));
#endif
});
```

now, the only thing remaining is actually using the callback:

```cs
public partial class MyPage : BaseContentPage
{
    // ...

    public override async void OnAppeared()
    {
        base.OnAppeared();
        
        // do whatever now
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```cs
`VisualElement` is the base class for most `Microsoft.Maui.Control`s:

    public partial class NameOfThePage : ContentPage
    {
        public NameOfThePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += NameOfThePage_Loaded;
        }

        private void NameOfThePage_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /* animations you want to trigger */
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately no OnLoad() to override.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The Loaded event is triggered before "OnNavigatedTo" and before "OnAppearing" events. So, this won't work. However, it is good to know we have an event to trigger before those events.